# Android: how to integrate a 'report abuse' mechanism in my app.?

Tags: android, parse-platform, report, spam-prevention

I'm currently working on my first serious app., and I would like to have some sort of contol on the data that users can enter.
Specifically, my app. allows users to write some text content (imagine something like a 'tweet'), and upload pictures.
I would like to prevent them from writing inappropriate text, and uploading offensive pictures for instance. 
What I thought of doing, is to allow something like 'report abuse' button, where users who find some content offesive, can press - in which case relevent data will be saved, and later checked, to decide if indeed an inappropriate usage happened (maybe by some sort of server-side code).

As I said, I'm a beginner in android development, and I would really love to hear your suggestions and guiding. Perhaps it is something over my league for now? Maybe you know of such thing that already exists?

**My app. uses Parse.com as its DB.**

I would really appriciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing as well an app with parse and I also had to integrate in it a report button for the user.

**The way I did it is simple:**

In every Pf User object, I created a field of type counter named "reportCounter" while in the PFObject created by the user (it can be a string, a picture, etc.)I created a boolean field named "isReported". When a user find some inappropriate content he can report it through the dedicated button. The PFObject relative to that content gets its isReported field changed to YES and a parse background job checks every day for all the PFObjects, incrementing the reportCounter field of the owner-creator of the content and sending a report e-mail to the administrator. In this way you can keep also a record to see if a particular user is behaving badly. Just take a look at the Parse documentation about background-jobs. It's pretty good.
I hope this will help.